# How do I persist an Auth0 Access Token in my Angular application upon reload since tokens are no longer stored in localStorage?

Tags: angular, jwt, access-token, reload, auth0

Auth0 seems to have recently adopted a better practice of not storing access tokens in localStorage. I agree with this decision. However, how does one now persist an access token in an Angular application so the user doesn't have to re-authenticate when they reload the page? The current tutorials seem to hinge on storing the token as a property on an authentication service, but the service is re-instantiated upon reload. What is the current best practice to persist the token?

The auth0.parseHash function will only return a valid authResult when a login attempt has been made. But any subsequent reloads would require the user to log in again in order to return a valid authResult value.

```
public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
        if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
            window.location.hash = '';
            this.localLogin(authResult);
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        } else if (err) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is a [link](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens) describing how to deal with tokens for _Auth0_. Long story short, for SPA they recommend requesting a new token on page load and keeping token only in memory... They also suggest _cookies_ (with certain drawbacks), so that can be a viable option...